# Excel vba Hide worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have serveral worksheets with macro's, some worksheets use other worksheets in the macro.
I only want to have 1 worksheet visible and the rest  must behidden. If i hide the worksheets the macro's do not run.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Don't use `.Select` in your' macros'.

Answer (score 0):

If the worksheet is hidden and the macro doesn't unhide the sheet first then it won't work. You could add some simple code to cope with it such as:

```
If sheets("sheet1").visible = false
Then sheets("sheet1").visible = true
```

This will test to see if it is visible and then unhide it if not.

Comment: Is it really worth putting this in `If` statement? I mean, in this way Excel have to perform at least one operation and sometimes two. If you do just `sheets("sheet1").visible = true` Excel performs always one operation and it doesn't generate error even if Sheet1 is visible.

Comment: I always add it into an if statement. If you have been looking at a tab and forget to hide it, and then the vba tries to unhide it again, it will fall over. Putting it in an if statement will solve that. Or else you could use   'On error resume next' I suppose

Comment: Unhiding sheet that is not hidden doesn't result in error.

Comment: All of the options of the [Worksheet.Visible Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197786.aspx) should be discussed. The [XlSheetVisibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821673.aspx) constants contain **xlSheetVisible** (True or -1), **xlSheetHidden** (False or 0) AND **xlSheetVeryHidden** (2 not True or False). The latter not only hides the worksheet but also removes it from the list of worksheets that can be 'unhidden'. If a worksheet is xlSheetVeryHidden then it does not compare directly to False.

Comment: But then if the macro has been excecuted i have to hide it again?

Comment: simply add the reverse at the end
  If sheets("sheet1").visible = true
  Then sheets("sheet1").visible = false

@EganWolf sometimes I find it does